# Flutter images not loaded (EXCEPTION: resolving an image codec)

Tags: image, dart, flutter, codec

When I try to run images assets doesn't get properly loaded, I am getting an exception:

> The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec: Unable to load asset: /images/p8.png`

Some weeks ago it was working and now it stopped. I tried to run from different pc and mac too (with simulator) anв still no images can be loaded. Fonts instead are properly loaded.

This is how I load the images, they are rendered inside a `GridView`
Below is the code:

```
return new Expanded(
      child: new GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 25.0, 16.0, 4.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            new MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/biliardo');
              },
              child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Image(
                    //parte importante, definire gli asset per trovarli più velocemnte
                    //si inseriscono nel pubspec.yaml
                    image: new AssetImage('/images/p8.png'),
                    height: 100.0,
                    width: 100.0,
                  ),
                  new Text(
                    "BILIARDO",
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      color: (darkTheme) ? Colors.blue : Colors.black,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),

            .....

    );
```

pubsec.yaml file code:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/emptyBall.png
    - images/p1.png
    - images/p2.png
    - images/p3.png
    - images/p4.png
    - images/p5.png
    - images/p6.png
    - images/p7.png
    - images/p8.png
    - images/p9.png
    - images/p10.png
    - images/p11.png
    - images/p12.png
    - images/p13.png
    - images/p14.png
    - images/p15.png
    - images/basket.png
    - images/volley.png
    - images/tennis.png
    - images/rugby.png
    - images/numbers.png
  fonts:
    - family: ShotClock
      fonts:
        - asset: utils/ShotClock.ttf
```

### Logs

flutter analyze

```
Analyzing D:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app...
No issues found!
Ran in 5.2s
```

flutter -v run

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/133Z7029VGJXBDCYLgCrj09F9cLbvIQQ5X8yBS4pPC7I/edit?usp=sharing
```

### Flutter Doctor

flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.3.1, on Microsoft Windows [Versione 10.0.16299.371], locale it-IT)
    • Flutter version 0.3.1 at C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision 12bbaba9ae (12 days ago), 2018-04-19 23:36:15 -0700
    • Engine revision 09d05a3891
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.48.0.flutter-fe606f890b

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Zanini\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 24.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

[√] Connected devices (1 available)
    • Nexus 5X • 01cde5e7db8d4c14 • android-arm64 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Which directory contains the `images` directory?

Comment: The question where the `images` directory is, is still not answered.

Comment: they are inside images folder in project root, sorry for the late reply

Comment: Did you use a leading `/` as pointed out in the answer below in the code that loads the image?

Comment: yes, my bad. :(

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Get rid of the leading `/` in your path to the png. It should be `images/p8.png`.

Also, consider using the cleaner `Image.asset` constructor, for example:

`new Image.asset('images/p8.png', width: 100.0, height: 100.0)`

Answer (score 29):

One thing to note is the 'assets:' tag must be correctly indented with the 'flutter:' tag, but it only throws an error **occasionally** when loading an asset.  So this won't work:

```
flutter: 
assets:
    - images/
```

But this will:

```
flutter: 
  assets:
    - images/
```

Comment: Why doesn't flutter indicate that it is in fact that?

Comment: Thanks! In my case i did the same mistake!! Solved!

Answer (score 15):

with new flutter version you also could put folders in pubspec.yaml, not only files

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/
```

Comment: Not able to do this, even after an upgrade. What version was this introduced?

Answer (score 14):

Add '/' correctly in all image paths

In Android Studio,

Tools->Flutter->Flutter Clean

Answer (score 6):

1. Close the emulator
2. Type "flutter clean" in your terminal (without quotation).
3. Run your App again.
4. It'll work fine for you.

Comment: This is what most of the other answers already stated. Duplicate answers should not be posted and will be deleted. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27980732).

Comment: Thank you!!!!! This fixed my problem, I was trying everything. Turns out I just needed to run flutter clean XD Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Besides the directory path make sure your image is valid, I have a png file which was not supported that was causing this error.. just make sure by opening the image in any image viewer to confirm the file is supported...

Comment: could you suggest an "image viewer" to use?

Comment: I used Windows image viewer itself

Comment: I had a normal .png file that opens fine as an image file, but Flutter throws this (EXCEPTION: resolving an image codec). I exported it to .jpg then Flutter displayed it. I wonder what codecs Flutter supports and how to provide support of all standard codecs that fall under .png filetype

Comment: Stranger thing to me is that sometimes my png is loaded, but others is not. It tends to throw this exception particularly in the beginning of the app run

Answer (score 3):

Beside the problems other stated, when adding new image assets, a cold reload is necessary to display new assets. If that does not help, `flutter clean` should solve the problems.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, came here looking for just what's expected as it isn't a codec issue and got a hodge-podge of answers.
What I've found from the documentation. For further explanation this directory should be in the project root Not under src or lib.

In pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/my_icon.png
    - assets/background.png
```

To include all assets under a directory, specify the directory name with the / character at the end:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - directory/
    - directory/subdirectory/
```

Let's say I did the following; where the images dir has multiple.

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

With my project structure simplified as

```
projectName
  ...
  lib
  pubspec.yaml
  assets
    images
      file1.png
      etc...
  ...
```

Then in a widget just do (Hint* the full path is required...)
I thought if assets already had the path the PATH was in context of the app. This was my mistake. Then do a flutter clean and run it should work fine.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/file1.png')),
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Clean
Then Rerun the project (Not hot reload)

By this 2 steps I am able to solve same issue. If pupspec.yaml file is Indented as Rules.

Answer (score 0):

i am developping on Windows 10 and not MAC OS X nor Linux i had the same problem...in fact the solution for me was just to change the unix like path separator : **'/'** by the one for windows environnement : **'\'** in the dart/flutter file

So in the pubspec.yaml images/mypicture.jpg
And in the dart file : When instanciating your object with :

child new Images.asset('images\\mypicture.jpg')

The double anti slash : **\\ is too escape the \ character**....

Hope it will help many Windows plateform based developers with flutter

This make it work on the Android emulator, but **on the Physical Mobile i suppose you will need before packaging to change in the other way using slash instead /** try both...

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure but can fix the problem:

- It often causes the CODEC problem if one widget uses the root directory whereas an another widget uses the sub-directory.
- avoid using sub-directory (such as "- images/") in the pubspec.yaml file, for example avoid using:

  ```
  flutter:   
    uses-material-design: true

    assets:
      - images/
  ```

***INSTEADE USE:***

```
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:

    - 'FILENAME WITH ITS EXTENSION'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you include that asset in pubspec.yaml file like this

```
     # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/icon-48.png
    - assets/images/icon-480.png
    - assets/images/icon-400.png
    - assets/images/qr.png
    - assets/images/bulb.png
    - assets/images/google_logo.png
```

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, I spent almost two hours seeing the error and the answer was so simple.

In the assets directory, I forgot to put the forward slash (`/`) because I didn't want to load the image.

[image: Solution]

Comment: It's better to share code snippets using ```code blocks``` instead of images. With code blocks, the snippets can be easily read and shared. It'll also helpful if you can explain how or why your answer solves the issue. Here are other tips on how to write a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this problem. I just hot restarted my app instead of hot reload and it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Wasted 3 hours on this. In the end I realised I had to move the "assets" stuff down to the very bottom of the yaml file and paste it under the last flutter: use 2 spaces before assets: and 4 before - assets/

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above solutions work, change image format to JPG.
e.g.

```
image.png --> image.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why we get this error even after doing everything correctly is changes like addition/removal of dependencies and assets requires complete restart. Hot reload isn't just sufficient for that. So when you restart all these assets and dependencies will then my tagged along with respective procedures.

Checklist of things to resolve this error

1. Check whether pubspec.yaml is valid. (One can validate it through this [link](http://www.yamllint.com/))
2. Check for typos
3. Restart your application instead of hotreload

Answer (score 0):

If using classes to declare dependencies like this

```
class Assets {
  static const String image1 = 'assets/images/image1.jpg';
  static const String image2 = 'assets/images/image2.jpg';
}
```

Solution - is to create a new class & add the below lines to the new class.

```
class NewAssets {
  static const String image1 = 'assets/images/image1.jpg';
  static const String image2 = 'assets/images/image2.jpg';
}
```

Reason - is that the old class containing the lines is or may be corrupted.

Even if you name the class the same as before it will still work - as the underlaying unique ID associated for that class (internal binary) is now changed to new unique ID.

Comment: This is how I solved for me.