# Flutter: Unable to load asset

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, assets

I cant Upload image as a background to a container, i have added the image in assets folder and added it to pubspec.yaml and showing me that error :

```
I/flutter ( 6664): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 6664): The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter ( 6664): Unable to load asset: assets/images/img.png
I/flutter ( 6664): 
I/flutter ( 6664): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 6664): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
I/flutter ( 6664): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 6664): #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:484:44)
I/flutter ( 6664): #2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:469:14)
I/flutter ( 6664): #3      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:327:17)
I/flutter ( 6664): #4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:160:22)
I/flutter ( 6664): #5      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:325:84)
I/flutter ( 6664): (elided 13 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter ( 6664): 
I/flutter ( 6664): Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/img.png")
I/flutter ( 6664): Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#99877(), name: "assets/images/img.png",
I/flutter ( 6664):   scale: 1.0)
I/flutter ( 6664): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

code :

```
body: Form(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
               Container(
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   image: DecorationImage(
                     image: AssetImage("assets/images/img.png"),
                     fit: BoxFit.cover,
                   ),
                 ),
```

I have added

```
assets:
  - assets/images/
```

to pubspec.yaml

the image folder

[image: the image folder]

and at

```
assets:
  - assets/images/img.png
```

---

```
I/flutter ( 6664): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 6664): The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter ( 6664): Unable to load asset: assets/images/img.png
I/flutter ( 6664): 
I/flutter ( 6664): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 6664): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
I/flutter ( 6664): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 6664): #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:484:44)
I/flutter ( 6664): #2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:469:14)
I/flutter ( 6664): #3      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:327:17)
I/flutter ( 6664): #4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:160:22)
I/flutter ( 6664): #5      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:325:84)
I/flutter ( 6664): (elided 13 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter ( 6664): 
I/flutter ( 6664): Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/img.png")
I/flutter ( 6664): Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#c1182(), name: "assets/images/img.png",
I/flutter ( 6664):   scale: 1.0)
I/flutter ( 6664): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: I realized I was using .svg asset and I had to use SvgPicture.asset('assets/imgs/reset-password.svg') to load svg image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need add like that

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/img.png
```

Comment: i have updated it as you tell yes and gives me the error i added to answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130933/flutter-images-not-loaded-exception-resolving-an-image-codec check this answers

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images and more detail

Comment: sorry in my pubspec.yaml it was  `assets:
    - assets/images/img.png`  not `flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/img.png`  thanks very much

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I needed **package** property as the image was in my **library** project and I was running the **example** project.

**package: [your parent directory or project name]**

eg. My project name is *'flutter_demo'*

```
AssetImage('assets/images/ic_welcome.png', package: 'flutter_demo'),
```

**pubspect.yaml**

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

**Directory structure:**

```
flutter_demo
  -- assets
    -- images
      -- ic_welcome.png
```

Comment: I am creating a flutter package and unable to load asset in many ways, you save my day broz. thank a lot

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error and here's how I solved it:

- First make sure the assets folder is located at the root of your project, outside the lib folder.
- Check there's no slash in front of the image path string inside AssetImage().
- Check the file name and path is correct in both the pubspec.yaml and AssetImage.
- Always remember to save the file and hot reload after making changes.
- For svg files, use the [flutter_svg package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg).

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
flutter:
  assets:
    -android/assests/directory/
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, if your files are in subdirectories, try to add subdirectories not only the parent directory.
Something like

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/subdirectory1/
    - assets/subdirectory2/
```

instead of

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```