# Why is flutter showing multiple past errors on run?

Tags: flutter, dart

I recently updated flutter and now a problem seems to occur when I run the project using flutter run.

Indeed, a list of all the errors I had previously is being shown on the screen (which is obviously getting bigger and bigger over time). I tried to recreate a new project and the problem still occurred. Here's an exemple: I didn't include my assets in the pubsec.yml file which obviously triggered an error at first. And now, while it's solved, it still shows on the log. Here it is:

```
Using hardware rendering with device SM A520F. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A520F in debug mode...
I/flutter ( 5746): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 5746): The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter ( 5746): Unable to load asset: assets/images/image.png
I/flutter ( 5746):
I/flutter ( 5746): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 5746): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
I/flutter ( 5746): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 5746): #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:484:44)
I/flutter ( 5746): #2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:469:14)      
I/flutter ( 5746): #3      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:327:17)
I/flutter ( 5746): #4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:160:22)
I/flutter ( 5746): #5      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:325:84) 
I/flutter ( 5746): (elided 13 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter ( 5746):
I/flutter ( 5746): Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/image.png")
I/flutter ( 5746): Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#00e61(), name: "assets/images/image.png",
I/flutter ( 5746):   scale: 1.0)
I/flutter ( 5746): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        11.5s
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...                        16.8s
Syncing files to device SM A520F...
 5,175ms (!)

�  To hot reload changes while running, press "r". To hot restart (and rebuild state), press "R".  
An Observatory debugger and profiler on SM A520F is available at: http://127.0.0.1:19977/p6C-c9NLr_E=/
For a more detailed help message, press "h". To detach, press "d"; to quit, press "q".
```

This problem occurred using the emulator first, then I switched to test it on my phone and it just cleared the log but the problem persisted, it just started all over. So, I tried to clear app data and uninstall the app from the emulator and it didn't solve a thing and this time it didn't started from scratch.

I'm a bit lost and this is starting to be a bit annoying over time to have this massive log of errors in which I don't know which one is real and which is not.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Some asked for the pubsec file

```
name: barty
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  gradient_app_bar: ^0.1.3
  scoped_model: ^0.3.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.1+1
  flutter_map: ^0.8.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/image.png
    - assets/images/2.0x/image.png
    - assets/images/3.0x/image.png
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  fonts:
    - family: Nunito
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Nunito-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Nunito-BoldItalic.ttf
          weight: 700
          style: italic
        - asset: assets/fonts/Nunito-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/Nunito-SemiBoldItalic.ttf
          weight: 600
          style: italic
        - asset: assets/fonts/Nunito-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/Nunito-RegularItalic.ttf
          weight: 400
          style: italic
        - asset: assets/fonts/Nunito-Light.ttf
          weight: 200
        - asset: assets/fonts/Nunito-Light.ttf
          weight: 200
          style: italic
        - asset: assets/fonts/Nunito-ExtraLight.ttf
          weight: 100
        - asset: assets/fonts/Nunito-ExtraLightItalic.ttf
          weight: 100
          style: italic
```

And how I declare the image

```
                Container(
                  width: 230,
                  height: 150,
                  child: Image.asset("assets/images/image.png"),
                ),
```

Comment: can you please show your code which place you define your images and at all?

Comment: add punspec.yaml file

Comment: From your description, it tells that maybe it cannot find the image location or your declaration is wrong. check out this link it will give you the idea of how it works.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130933/flutter-images-not-loaded-exception-resolving-an-image-codec

Comment: The thing is that it I had this error before during the execution, fixed it, and it's showing up now when I flutter run. Which wasn't the case with the previous version of flutter.

Comment: I have had the same issue since upgrading to the latest stable version of Flutter. Whenever you start the application it shows you old log messages and errors. I wonder if it is a regression of this issue:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4874

Comment: I guess that's it glad to see I'm not the only one experiencing it