# Unable to load asset Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

When I try to load image selected from gallery to be displayed on my app on first run, it comes up with this error.

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: /data/user/0/com.example.app_test/cache/image_picker5494866148665379741.jpg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:225:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:668:31)
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:651:14)
#3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:504:13)
...
Image provider: ExactAssetImage(name: "/data/user/0/com.example.app_test/cache/image_picker5494866148665379741.jpg", scale: 1.0, bundle: null)
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#d8a39(), name: "/data/user/0/com.example.versus_pay_client/cache/image_picker5494866148665379741.jpg", scale: 1.0)
====================================================================================================
```

When I hot reload the app the image gets displayed.

```
Future getImage() async {
pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

setState(() {
  if (pickedFile != null) {
    image = File(pickedFile.path);
  } else {
    print('No image selected.');
  }
});
```

```
new Container(
   height: 120.0,
   width: 120.0,
   decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      image: new DecorationImage(
      image: new ExactAssetImage(image.path),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
   ),
   borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
      const Radius.circular(90.0)),
     ),
   ),
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130933/flutter-images-not-loaded-exception-resolving-an-image-codec

Comment: @fartem this doesn't solve my issue. Thanks

Comment: Which package are you using? Maybe you can give a try to package image_picker, I've used it in one project and worked really well.

Comment: @RodrigoCardozo I'm using the image_picker.

Answer (score 5):

I'd run into same problem, this is because the new version of image_picker picks the file from camera/gallery and then writes it to a temporary storage in the root of the application, It means the file is not an asset. You can use FileImage instead, like this:

```
new Container(
  height: 120.0,
  width: 120.0,
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    image: new DecorationImage(
      image: new FileImage(image),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(90.0)),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Its worked,, Thanks